# richTextBox sum of all lines in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, richtextbox

I'm learning to code and to get started I am creating small projects. I want to get the sum of all the lines in a richTextBox. All the lines in the richTextBox are numbers.

For example:
 - 1 
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
 - 5
 - 6
 - 7
 - 8
 - 9
 - 10

The result must be: 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55.
I want to display the result in a messagebox: "The sum is 55".

Comment: "Is there any way....?" - the answer is yes. If you want help with a specific problem, though, you need to show what you have tried. Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum of your numbers is {0}",
    richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').Select(number => Convert.ToInt32(number)).Sum()));
```

Split text on new line character, convert everything from string array to numbers, get sum and display it in `MessageBox`.

Step by step solution:

```
string[] stringArray = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');

int sum = 0;
foreach (string element in stringArray)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(element);
}

MessageBox.Show("Sum of your numbers is " + sum);
```

Comment: @Michielvk Well, it means text you entered in richTextBox is not in correct number format. This is tested on the same example you described in your question and is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To do this it is necessary to divide the `contents` of the control `RichTextBox` in rows, performing the conversion for each line of type int and then performing the sum of all the numbers. Below is the implementation of the `Sum` method, responsible for adding and return the result:

```
    private int Sum()
    {
        //myrichtextbox is your rich control
        string myText = myrichtextbox.Text;
        var separators = new string[] { "\n" };
        var myNumbers = myText.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int sum = 0;

        foreach (var num in myNumbers)
        {
            int convertedNumber;
            if (Int32.TryParse(num, out convertedNumber))
                sum += convertedNumber;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

End to display the result in a `MessageBox` use the following statement:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The sum result is: {0}.",Sum()));
```

Detail: I'm assuming you're using Windows Forms Application!

Comment: This answer helpful to you?

Comment: wait a moment I will implement in windows forms then!

Comment: The case is now implemented in windows forms.